# Django forloop and all selectable radio buttons

Tags: python, django, django-forms, bootstrap-4

Here is a seemingly simple task, creating a form using a set of records so the user can choose which record to go for, all using a radio button.

```
<form action="" method="GET">{% csrf_token %}
{% for record in select_records %}
    <div class="form-check indent-3"> 

        <label class="form-check-label" for="radio{{forloop.counter}}">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio{{forloop.counter}}" name="{{record.get_model_name}}{{record.id}}" value="{{record.record_name}}">

            {% if request.user.userprofile.head_shot_thumb %}

                <img src="{{ request.user.userprofile.head_shot_thumb }}" alt="Proforma creator"> 

            {% else %}

                <div class="h2-li ">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i> 
                </div>
            {% endif %}

            {{ record.record_name }} - {{ record.date_created }}
        </label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that the form creates a list of radio buttons which are all selectable, just like how all the checkboxes are selectable.

I have searched and compared my code to simple radio forms such as [the one at W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_radio&stacked=h), but I cannot figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Make sure the 'name' attribute is the same for all radio buttons belonging to the same group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did small changes in your code. Check it below.

```
<form action="" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for record in select_records %}
    <div class="form-check indent-3"> 
        <label class="form-check-label" for="radio{{forloop.counter}}">
            <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" id="radio{{forloop.counter}}" name="record-option" value="{{record.record_name}}">
            {% if request.user.userprofile.head_shot_thumb %}
                <img src="{{ request.user.userprofile.head_shot_thumb }}" alt="Proforma creator"> 
            {% else %}
                <div class="h2-li ">
                    <i class="fas fa-user"></i> 
                </div>
            {% endif %}
            {{ record.record_name }} - {{ record.date_created }}
        </label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

I hope this will help you. :)